# Allen Browne's ConcatRelated() Error 3061: Too few parameters

Tags: sql, concatenation, ms-access-2016

I am trying to create a list of products at a given warehouse. 
Allen Browne's ConcatRelated() function seems to be the tried and true method to create lists using when a linked variable is the same, but I can't get it to work.

I have broken my information down into a single query... "qry_Products"

```
SELECT qry_AX_LineItems_LINES.Warehouse, tblREF_Chemical.[Sales Name]
FROM qry_AX_LineItems_LINES INNER JOIN tblREF_Chemical ON 
qry_AX_LineItems_LINES.ItemId = tblREF_Chemical.[Item Number]
GROUP BY qry_AX_LineItems_LINES.Warehouse, tblREF_Chemical.[Sales Name];
```

It produces a table with the Sales Name and Warehouse(s).

What I need to see happen is a list of the Sales Names when their warehouse matches.

I have tried using the function in a textbox of my form...

```
=ConcatRelated("[Sales Name]","[qry_Products]"," Warehouse ='" & [Warehouse] 
& "'")
```

It causes an Error 3061 and leaves the cell blank.

I double checked my syntax within the quotes by using Dlookup(), and it produced the first result of the list.

I have also tried altering my query...

```
SELECT qry_AX_LineItems_LINES.Warehouse, ConcatRelated("[Sales Name]"," 
[tblREF_Chemical]") AS Expr1
FROM qry_AX_LineItems_LINES INNER JOIN tblREF_Chemical ON 
qry_AX_LineItems_LINES.ItemId = tblREF_Chemical.[Item Number];
```

Unfortunately it then lists every product in my database as a list.

I also tried creating a new query to reference the one producing minimal information.

```
SELECT ConcatRelated("[Sales Name]","qry_Products") AS Expr1
FROM qry_Products;
```

I know that the initial query is correct but when I go to run the new query I get multiple pop-ups of Error 3061 and empty cells for results.

I double checked that I am copying the module exactly. [http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkYjl.png) 
Module is named "Concat".

I'm reading every help guide out there but I just can't see what I should try next.

Thank you so much for time and any advice!

[SubForm frm_LineItems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkYjl.png)

[Query qry_Products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AE3lJ.png)

Comment: What type of control is *Warehouse* on your form? Is it placed in a subform? With your form opened, run this in query designer (filling in form name) with no quotes: `SELECT [Sales Name] FROM [qry_Products] WHERE Warehouse = Forms!myform![Warehouse]`

Comment: I ran this and did get a column list of products.
I have [frm_SalesOrderEntry] that allows the user to select a given sales order... That is integrated with my company operating system to pull the order information. While the order has a main warehouse operator, It is possible to have multiple warehouses under a single order and that is represented in a subform.

Comment: Column list of products? But this query runs *Sales Name*? Once again, is the *Warehouse* control located on a subform or not? Is it a combo box? Maybe screenshot your form for us.

Comment: The warehouse I need to reference is on a sub form, because there can be multiple warehouses present. I have included some images of my subform and working query.

Comment: When I try to reference the sub form I get a parameter request, it will let me reference the main form, but then I only get one warehouse worth of values and they are still in a column.

Comment: Do you get a 3061 when you try it like this `SELECT ConcatRelated("tblREF_Chemical.[Sales Name]","qry_Products") AS Expr1
FROM qry_Products;`

Comment: #Jimmy Smith, Unfortunately yes.

Answer (score 1):

I found another thread that gives an alternative to the Allen Browne method. 
https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/569535-combining-rows-opposite-union

This seems to be working.

```
'Concat Returns lists of items which are within a grouped field
Public Function Concat(strGroup As String, strItem As String) As String
Static strLastGroup As String
Static strItems As String

If strGroup = strLastGroup Then
    strItems = strItems & ", " & strItem
Else
    strLastGroup = strGroup
    strItems = strItem
End If
Concat = strItems
End Function
```

with Query SQL

```
SELECT WH,
Max(Concat(WH, [Sales Name])) AS Products
FROM [qry_Products]
GROUP BY WH
```

I wanted to leave this here in case anyone else was having a similar issue.