# MS Access: Consolidate Query Data on a Form

Tags: ms-access

I am putting together an MS Access database of our contacts for bidding purposes.  I am at the point in the build where I would like to expand and display details of a company when you click a button.  I have programmed the button to run my query and display the data on a form.  The issue I am running into is: my data is being duplicated.  For example:

I have a company (tbl_Company)

That company has 3 contacts (tbl_Contacts)

That company also has 2 licenses it holds (tbl_CoLic)

My query output is 6 rows of data, each contact with each license.

My end goal is to display on a form each company with all of their details, without duplicating other information.  I have a total of 6 tables with different company details, each of those 6 tables can have one or more records associated with each company.

I can run separate queries to populate listboxes for each detail, but that seems cumbersome.  Is there a better way?  Please note this is all being done in MS Access, not SQL Server.  Here is my query now:

```
    SELECT tbl_Company.[Company Name], tbl_Contact.[First Name], tbl_Contact.[Last Name], tbl_CoLic.[License Number], tbl_CoLic.[License Code], tbl_CoLic.[Primary License], tbl_CoWA.County, tbl_CoPS.[Project Size], tbl_CoRef.District, tbl_CoRat.Rating, tbl_CoRat.Notes
    FROM (((((tbl_Company INNER JOIN tbl_CoPS ON tbl_Company.[Company ID] = tbl_CoPS.[Company ID]) INNER JOIN tbl_CoRat ON tbl_Company.[Company ID] = tbl_CoRat.[Company ID]) INNER JOIN tbl_CoRef ON tbl_Company.[Company ID] = tbl_CoRef.[Company ID]) INNER JOIN tbl_CoLic ON tbl_Company.[Company ID] = tbl_CoLic.[Company ID]) INNER JOIN tbl_CoWA ON tbl_Company.[Company ID] = tbl_CoWA.[Company ID]) INNER JOIN tbl_Contact ON tbl_Company.[Company ID] = tbl_Contact.[Company ID]
    WHERE (((tbl_Company.[Company ID])=[TempVars]![Details]));
```

Screenshot of Sample Data
[image: Design View of Query]
[image: Table View of Query]

Comment: Then you need to build form with subforms. Or better, a report, not a form, perhaps with subreports. Data should be posted as text table, not image. This is a design issue, not programming, responses will essentially be opinions, and therefore question not really suited to SO. Another approach to consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789423/allen-brownes-concatrelated-error-3061-too-few-parameters

Comment: June7 knows a lot more than I do, but I disagree anyway because I feel interacting with the Access API is programming.  However I can see that in my hurry to finish the answer needs some polish on that point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access expects forms and reports to have one record source.  If you have a query or table with all the information your form needs you can just click it and access will build and manage a default form/report based on that one record source.  So An access friendly approach is to give any form/report a table with everything it needs.  So replicating your Database with some random suggestions and one important change -deleting the extra company name columns.

[image]

We can replicate your problem:

```
SELECT tbl_Company.CompanyName, tbl_Contact.FirstName, tbl_Contact.LastName, tbl_Colic.LicenseNumber, tbl_Colic.LicenseCode, tbl_Colic.PrimaryLicense, tbl_CoWA.County, tbl_CoWA.District, CompanyProjectSizes.ProjectSize, CompanyRatings.Rating, CompanyRatings.Notes
FROM ((((tbl_Company INNER JOIN tbl_Colic ON tbl_Company.CompanyID = tbl_Colic.CompanyID) INNER JOIN tbl_Contact ON tbl_Company.CompanyID = tbl_Contact.CompanyID) INNER JOIN tbl_CoWA ON tbl_Company.CompanyID = tbl_CoWA.CompanyID) INNER JOIN CompanyProjectSizes ON tbl_Company.CompanyID = CompanyProjectSizes.CompanyID) INNER JOIN CompanyRatings ON tbl_Company.CompanyID = CompanyRatings.CompanyID;
```

[image]

What's going on is When we combine the multiple tables into 1 we run into a problem because we have 2 license codes and each license code gets its own row.  (rows in the combined table with any missing data are removed when inner joins are used.  The reason we see anything is the company id for Rebel Plumbing has been added to all the formerly empty tables)  The First part of your solution which sets up the next problem is to use a totals query.

```
SELECT tbl_Company.CompanyName, tbl_Contact.FirstName, tbl_Contact.LastName, First(tbl_Colic.LicenseNumber) AS FirstOfLicenseNumber, First(tbl_Colic.LicenseCode) AS FirstOfLicenseCode, First(tbl_Colic.PrimaryLicense) AS FirstOfPrimaryLicense, First(tbl_CoWA.County) AS FirstOfCounty, First(tbl_CoWA.District) AS FirstOfDistrict, First(CompanyRatings.Rating) AS FirstOfRating, First(CompanyRatings.Notes) AS FirstOfNotes
FROM ((((tbl_Company INNER JOIN CompanyProjectSizes ON tbl_Company.CompanyID = CompanyProjectSizes.CompanyID) INNER JOIN CompanyRatings ON tbl_Company.CompanyID = CompanyRatings.CompanyID) INNER JOIN tbl_Colic ON tbl_Company.CompanyID = tbl_Colic.CompanyID) INNER JOIN tbl_Contact ON tbl_Company.CompanyID = tbl_Contact.CompanyID) INNER JOIN tbl_CoWA ON tbl_Company.CompanyID = tbl_CoWA.CompanyID
GROUP BY tbl_Company.CompanyName, tbl_Contact.FirstName, tbl_Contact.LastName;
```

[image]
[image]
Now that you have the desired record source it works great in reports.  However in this case  When you create a form from your new record source the form quietly fails to update and edit!
What is going on is Access doesn't know how to change the tables in response to changes in the form.  Most of the problem here is the total query we used.  Here is a link describing when you can base a form on a query:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-a-query-as-the-record-source-for-a-form-or-report-e54251f3-57ca-4a7d-8e77-e498966cd41b

At this point There is not enough detail in the question to be specific about what to do.  You will have to divide data entry into at least two parts in most cases as we can't put all the information into one access friendly record source.  What parts will depend on user preference and how the rest of the data is structured.  For the data provided I took the base tables in a form-subforms approach using the company table as the record source for the form and the contact and license tables as the subforms:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.  Your input was basically what I suspected to be the case.  I will take care of the duplicated "Company" names in tables, I suspected those were redundant and not needed.