# SQL query with GROUP BY to return concatenated list of on FIELD

Tags: sql, ms-access, adodb, textjoin

I am using ADODB for excel to pull a list of undo entries from my undo table (Access database). The user will then select one of the "Undo:s" as defined by the unique combination of _MODIFIED_BY and _MODIFIED_TIME and then be able to retrieve all records related to that. A convenient way is to retrieve that by a list of ID:s.

So for the first Query I wish to create a list of all related ID:s (named _ORIG_ID:s) like this:

```
SELECT Count(*), [_MODIFIED_BY], [_MODIFIED_TIME], CONCAT([_ORIG_ID],',') AS _REL_IDS
FROM ANALYSES_UNDO
GROUP BY [_MODIFIED_BY], [_MODIFIED_TIME]
ORDER BY [_MODIFIED_TIME] DESC
```

Then the user will select one of the records from this query and I will then pull these ID:s from another table like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ANALYSES WHERE ID IN(XXX)
```

Where I will just replace the XXX with whatever was returned in _REL_IDS.

Is it possible to construct this query. Can ACCESS SQL even join a field like this? I know there is no function called CONCAT that works like this, but it was just defined to demonstrate my needs.

Comment: Please tag only one rdbms

Comment: You can use the & operator in a query to concatenate multiple fields into a single field in your result set.

Comment: I know this. This is not what I want. I want to return something like "4,5,12,33,34" which is a list of all _ORIG_ID:s in each GROUP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allen Browne's ConcatRelated() Error 3061: Too few parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789423/allen-brownes-concatrelated-error-3061-too-few-parameters). As shown in that posting, VBA can concatenate data from multiple records. However, the concatenated string will not work in the second SQL you propose.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to concatenate the data, it would be simpler to use the original query as a subquery in the second part.

To Demonstrate:
Original query (without the concat bit)

```
SELECT Count(*), [_MODIFIED_BY], [_MODIFIED_TIME], FIRST([_ORIG_ID])
FROM ANALYSES_UNDO
GROUP BY [_MODIFIED_BY], [_MODIFIED_TIME]
ORDER BY [_MODIFIED_TIME] DESC
```

Note the `FIRST([_ORIG_ID])` part - it's returning one of the correct IDs, the second query can just compare the fields of that, as below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ANALYSES 
INNER JOIN ANALYSES_UNDO ON ANALYSES.ID = ANALYSES_UNDO.[_ORIG_ID]
WHERE 
    ANALYSES_UNDO.[_MODIFIED_BY] = (SELECT U.[_MODIFIED_BY] FROM ANALYSES_UNDO U WHERE U.[_ORIG_ID] = XXX)
AND ANALYSES_UNDO.[_MODIFIED_TIME] = (SELECT U.[_MODIFIED_TIME] FROM ANALYSES_UNDO U WHERE U.[_ORIG_ID] = XXX)
```

The parameter `XXX` passed into this second query only needs to be a single `[_ORIG_ID]` and the query will return all other records with the same `MODIFIED_TIME` and `MODIFIED_BY`

Comment: Thanks. I am new to SQL. Haven't used JOIN before although I know approximately how it works. One question though. ANALYSES_UNDO may contain the same [_ORIG_ID] multiple times if the user has made multiple changes on the same record from [ANALYSES]. Only one change will match the correct modified time though. However, I am not sure if the temporary table created by INNER JOIN is created before the "WHERE" filter, but I assume the query filters ANALYSES_UNDO prior to "INNER JOIN", and there will be only one match?

Comment: OK, you're really going to need a unique ID in the `ANALYSES_UNDO` (if it doesn't have one already, you should put one in as it's best practice in database design), so you can get that unique ID from the first query and pass it as the filter to the second.

Comment: There is an unique ID Spencer. However the first query do no return undo entries one by one, but rather grouped by change time/user.

Comment: I have tried this query out now in many different ways @Spencer. I get an error every time. Run-time error '-2147217887': Invalid Memo, OLE, or Hyperlink Object in subquery 'U.[_MODIFIED_BY]'. However, I found a different way posted as an answer below. Frustrating though not to find why the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way that worked for me by using the returned [_MODIFIED_BY]=XXX and [_MODIFIED_TIME]=YYY by the query below:

```
SELECT * FROM ANALYSES WHERE ID=
ANY(SELECT [_ORIG_ID] FROM ANALYSES_UNDO WHERE [_MODIFIED_BY]=XXX AND [_MODIFIED_TIME]=YYY)
```