# Add CSV field with values from other table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this data:

Table A

```
pk name
1  Peter
2  Jon
```

Table B

```
pk trait    fk_A
1  funny    1
2  generous 1
3  rude     2
```

I want to get this result set:

```
pk name traits
1  Peter funny,generous
2  Jon   rude
```

How can I aggregate the trait column of table B and attach it as a CSV field 'traits' to table A?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I'm using Pythons pyodbc package to connect to a Microsoft Access database (.accdb file).

Comment: The answer to this depends on what kind of database you have, since the ansi SQL standard doesn't define a method to build up csv data. In general, this kind of aggregation is antithetical to the relational set theory that underpins SQL databases, and so is usually better done in client code or the reporting tool anyway, though most DBs do have support for it now.

Comment: Okay, Access is **NOT** one of the DBs that has support for this. There is no `string_agg()` or `group_concat()` method you can use. You'll have to  return multiple rows for each name, with one trait per row, and then roll up the data at a different level.

Comment: Oops, okay thank you! I know how to do it in my client code, I just thought it was best practice to do it on the query already if possible. Then I'll use Python / pandas to achieve it. Thank you!

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn The ISO/IEC 9075-2:2016 standard ("the SQL standard") does have a standard function to do just that, `LISTAGG` (defined in 10.9 <aggregate function>), but yes, it isn't implemented in MS Access.

Comment: https://modern-sql.com/feature/listagg

Comment: One more thing, in case someone finds this topic: my solution in the client code (python / pandas) uses a combination of groupby and apply(list) in order to aggregate table B into the proper shape before left joining it into table A. Don't forget to reset_index on table B before left joining it.

Comment: Cannot be done in Access with SQL alone, use VBA. And should not be attached to a table, just calculated in query as needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allen Browne's ConcatRelated() Error 3061: Too few parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789423/allen-brownes-concatrelated-error-3061-too-few-parameters)