# Microsoft Access combine like rows based on two columns

Tags: ms-access

I would like to combine like rows based on StudentID and Subject in the table below.

| StudentID | Subject | Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 393438 | Math | [AF15] |
| 393438 | Math | [DS1.4] |

I would like for the code column to join the unique values into one field. Example: The above table would become:

| StudentID | Subject | Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 393438 | Math | [AF15];[DS1.4] |

I have tried to merge the table with another table with unique records for studentid and subject. I am fairly new at MS Access and still learning. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allen Browne's ConcatRelated() Error 3061: Too few parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789423/allen-brownes-concatrelated-error-3061-too-few-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Use my fast function [DJoin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62589561/3527297):

```sql
SELECT 
    Student.StudentID, 
    Student.Subject, 
    DJoin("[Code]","Student","",";") AS Codes
FROM 
    Student
GROUP BY 
    Student.StudentID, 
    Student.Subject;
```

Output:

[image]