# MS Access or SQL developer - records with multiple values help needed

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot-table

I have a table in my database which contains this info;

[image: Table info]

The CUST_NO can appear multiple times.
The DATE can be the same, even on the same record.

I want to get the output to look like this
[image: Output]

I'm not sure how to do this. Basically its a count where it displays the actual record.

I tried a few things but I'm very new to this. I feel the date might be confusing things, the value could be anything.

Thanks in advance world!

Comment: Data should be provided as formatted text table, not image. Need a unique identifier field, such as autonumber.

Comment: Alternative uses VBA: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789423/allen-brownes-concatrelated-error-3061-too-few-parameters